# Prevent Overflow while passing Integer.MAX_VALUE+1 parameter to a method(int var)

Tags: java, parameters, overflow

How can I prevent an int overflow, if I'm passing an `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1` parameter to a `method(int var)`?

Example:

```
public class Hello {

    void test(int var){
        System.out.println(var);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        hello.test(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. What behavior are you expecting? Why not just use a `long` instead?

Comment: I'm going to give you a bucket holding 2 litres of water that can only hold 1 litre of water. You can't.

Comment: By the time `test` receives the value of `var`, it has already been calculated. No way to tell if it was called with `MAX_VALUE+1` or `MIN_VALUE` (or any number of other expressions).

Comment: void test(long var) = same result!

Comment: Try it with `+ 1L`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot **"prevent"** the overflow. This is obvious because the `int` data type has a value range. When adding numbers with the `+` operator, the result of `int + int` is of `int` type.

What you want to do is perhaps prevent unexpected results, in which case you'd rather want to know that an overflow has occurred. For that, you can use:

```
try {
    Math.addExact(a, b);
} catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
    // If this exception is raised, then you know
    // that an overflow occured, and you can handle it
    // more appropriately.
}
```

With this, you can handle the case of an overflow and not use unexpected values. But the overflow still occurred. 

When your test is done on this method:

```
Math.addExact(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1)
```

The following exception is raised:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException thrown: integer overflow
      at Math.addExact (Math.java:825)
```

Your other option is to use `long` to allow for larger values. For this, you'd need to cast at least one of the values to `long`:

```
(long)Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1
```

This result in the `long` value `2147483648`

Comment: additional option: `BigInteger.intValueExact()`.... but not better (IMHO) than using `Math.addExact()`

Answer (score 1):

You can only prevent the integer overflow/underflow at addition, by putting a check before the operation and moving to next bigger primitive datatype if required.

```
public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello hello = new Hello();
        int value = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int toAdd = 1;

        if (hello.isSafeAdd(value, toAdd)) {
            hello.test(value + toAdd);
        } else {
            hello.test((long) value + toAdd);
        }
    }

    boolean isSafeAdd(int value, int toAdd) {
        return !(toAdd > 0 ? value > Integer.MAX_VALUE - toAdd : toAdd < Integer.MIN_VALUE - value);
    }

    void test(long var) {
        System.out.println(var);
    }

    void test(int var) {
        System.out.println(var);
    }

}
```